# HTML5 LocalStorage seems to become corrupt

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, local-storage

I'm using BootUp.js (https://github.com/TradeMe/bootup.js) to load and store CSS and JavaScript files into HTML5 LocalStorage. The site is mobile focused so the time saving and speed boost this creates is great! However, I've noticed the odd occasion were the CSS (never noticed it with JS) becomes corrupt in the storage and so the site renders horribly until the storage is cleared and the CSS files are refetched from the server.

I've seen this happen very sporadically on Safari on an iPhone 4 (iOS 6), Chrome on a Galaxy S3 and Chrome on a Nexus 7 - so it doesn't seem to be limited to any particular device, browser or OS. Is this an issue any one has come across before? Is it possible that the data has just somehow become corrupt? Are there any known issues with WebKit (I guess) that could cause it?

I'm planning to implement a work-around by storing some kind of checksum that can be generated in JS to ensure the data is fully there. If not, clear it out and fetch from the server.

Comment: I am not familiar with bootup, but does it perform some form of minifying of the CSS? This could explain why css and not js is affected.

Comment: My CSS is already minified. Bootup just stores it in local storage as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first use this:
http://arty.name/localstorage.html

Mobile browsers tend to cut back on storage space due to obvious memory limitations. Your CSS and Javascript might be too big, even when minified.

Other thing I can think of for this behavior is that `localStorage` might become corrupt when starting a save, and refreshing the page at the same time. I'm not familiar with the exact works of browsers, but I'm guessing they might stop a save in the middle.

Also, have a look here:
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/there-is-no-simple-solution-for-local-storage/